# Visual Studio 2010 unresponsive on startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I launch Visual Studio 2010, the inner work area screen always goes black or white and the title bar says VS is not responding. It does this for about 20 seconds before returning to normal operation.

Does anyone else experience this, and how can it be fixed?

Windows Vista32 with 2GB RAM, ATI Radeon 4850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you have enough RAM to handle visual studio during start up.  I experienced this on my previous machine (vista32 2GB RAM) before buying a new Windows 7 64 bit 8 GB RAM and now everything works fine.

Comment: I see. Come to think of it a few of my other programs say "not responding" when I launch them but only Visual Studio and Blend go black/white. I plan on upgrading to Windows 7 64 soon but I suppose more ram in the meantime wont hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this incredibly useful.  [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/)   Simply install it and go to the File Menu / Recent projects and Recent Files and clear the list.  That will speed up visual studio signficantly.